# How to use a trigger to affect related grid elements?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

As an exercise in WPF I am dabbling with a Sudoku-like grid.

Consider the following (simplified) example

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SO_WPF_Question_Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_WPF_Question_Sample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MouseOverStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <!-- I want something to happen here -->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                            <Label Content="{Binding}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource MouseOverStyle}"
                                   />
                    </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

</Window>
```

Code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Viewmodel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel // INotifyPropertyChanged omitted for simplicity
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        PopulateElements(4);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Cell> Items { get; set; }

    private void PopulateElements(int size)
    {
        int div = (int)Math.Sqrt(size);
        IList<Cell> items = new List<Cell>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                items.Add(new Cell()
                {
                    X = i,
                    Y = j,
                    Z = j / div + div * (i / div)
                });
            }
        }
        Items = items;
    }
}
```

POCO class

```
public class Cell
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Row: " + X + " Col: " + Y + " Box: " + Z;
    }
}
```

The only interesting bit: whenever I hover over a grid element, it turns red.

What I want: whenever I hover over a grid element, I want to highlight all 'sibling' cells as well. I.e. the ones where X, Y and Z are equal to those of the active cell.

I don't know how to achieve that, but I can think about some strategies.

Active strategy:
Upon the `Trigger`, somehow fire some method (something like a `Command`?) (or something else?), have that parse all `Cell`s in the grid, if they are siblings, set some property on them, and define a `Style` to respond to a `DataTrigger`.

Passive strategy:
Upon the trigger, set some ViewModel property that triggers an event that the `Cell`s subscribe to (`INotifyPropertChanged` springs to mind), have an event handler in `Cell` set a property and again have a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`. I can see this work in my mind but there is a coupling issue with this approach. Also, how would I convey the info about the grid element being hovered over?

While researching this I came across `EventTrigger` and `Interaction` but those seem to be primarily geared to animations. There is probably a better/simpler approach to this. I have the feeling I am overthinking this.

I would appreciate advice nudging me to an approach on how to tackle this and if possible why that approach would be favorable.

*Update* it turns out that what my question really boiled down to was how to call a `Command` (with a `CommandParameter`) using `EventTrigger`. There are a lot of answers on SO on this one, a lot of them involving MVVM Light. I solved it by using `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` and can now see how MVVM Light might have been the better/easier way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience alone I'm biased towards something along the lines of the first proposed solution.

Add the following namespaces to the xaml:

```
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

And then use EventToCommand:

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HoverCellCommand}"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the view model you'd have something like...

```
public RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs> HoverCellCommand {get; private set;}

HoverCellCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs>(p => 
{
   //find cell siblings, etc...
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I take it I need to install MVVM LIght for this, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should've mentioned that explicitly.

Comment: I will play around with this, I think it is what I am looking for. Not sure about rules for accepting it as an answer though, since it essentialy 'black-boxes' the issue I am struggling with. Please don't take this the wrong way: I really appreciate your input, but in my experience the SO community can be pretty unforgiving about stuff like this.

Comment: Some more feedback. Couldn't get MVVM Light to work. It probably works best when incorporated right at the start of a project. Plus it is a framework on top of a framework. Since my knowledge of WPF is shaky at best, I think I need to get a grasp of the basics a little more before I introduce more 'black-box' stuff, at least until I *understand* why the 'black-box' stuff is awasome (or not). Meanwhile I stumbled upon `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`. Saw some concepts in there that may help me too.

Comment: Quite possible. Best of luck with it.

Comment: FYI I updated the question to reflect why I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for myself, this is how I did it *without* using MVVM Light. Instead, I installed the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) package to get the `Behaviors` stuff (known as `Interactivity` in Blend)

First the basic stuff: create a command:

```
    public class ChangeSiblingColorCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<Cell> _action;

#pragma warning disable CS0067 // The event is never used
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
#pragma warning restore CS0067 // The event is never used

        public ChangeSiblingColorCommand(Action<Cell> action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return (parameter is Cell c);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action((Cell)parameter);
        }
    }
```

Then include the command in the viewmodel so it can be bound to:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    this.ChangeSiblingColorCommand = new ChangeSiblingColorCommand(HighlightSiblings);
}

public ICommand ChangeSiblingColorCommand { get; private set; }

private void HighlightSiblings(Cell cell)
{
    var siblings = cell.Siblings(Items);
    foreach (Cell c in siblings)
    {
        c.IsSiblingHighlighted = !c.IsSiblingHighlighted;
    }
}
```

Finally, hook the command up in the view using the following rather scary XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Label Style="{StaticResource MouseOverStyle}" Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UniformGrid,
                                                        Mode=FindAncestor},
                                                        Path=DataContext.ChangeSiblingColorCommand }"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UniformGrid,
                                                        Mode=FindAncestor},
                                                        Path=DataContext.ChangeSiblingColorCommand }"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Be sure to include this reference in the view:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```